# Basis and dimension of Ring as a vector space over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, finite-fields

I tried to solve following exercise:
[image]

My knowledge in algebra is a bit rusty, so I would appreciate it if you could help me remembering how to solve c). I realized that $|R| = 2^{128}$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait, $\Bbb F=\Bbb F_{256}$, isn't it? Anyway, to prove $R$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F$, you basically need to verify that multiplication with elements of $\Bbb F$ is well defined and well behaved with the addition.

Comment: I agree. That's what I realized so far, too. But how does it help me in finding a basis? Sry, I'm having a massive brain fart rn

Comment: Well, write up some elements of $R$ first, then try to write up a generic element. The dimension will be the number of $\Bbb F$-coefficients in a properly written generic element. To create a basis just put $1$ for a given coefficient and $0$ for the others. (Doing it with a general $\Bbb F$ might actually ease it up.)

Comment: Ohhhhh. I remember. Well. $dim_\mathbb{F} (R) = 16$ and basis consisting of monomials of degree $\leq 3$ if I calculated right.

Comment: I can not believe, I asked this question. Thanks a lot Berci!

Comment: Yes, that's it. And btw $|R|=256^{16}$.

Comment: I'm stuck at question (a)

Comment: You can show that $\mu(z)$ has no factors of degree $\leq 4$ by brute force (check that all irreducible polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ do not divide $\mu(z)$ and you are good to go). Recall that a polynomial of degree <= 3 is irreducible over a field iff it has no zeros